# How to send a "Address" from Javascript to Solidity Contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, addresses

Hi i have created frontend and working with web3js.
Now what i am trying to do is:

1. Updating the data in the contract.
2. Add the address in the contract (So here in form i am asking the user to put the address (Metamask address) and want to store this in  the contract that i have created.)

Now, the 1st one is correctly running and 2nd one is also running correctly but only in remix.
But, 2nd one is failing and showing error when i am sending the data to the contract from javascript.
Error i am getting:
[image]

Sending data like this:

[image]

Javascript Code:

[image]

I think that there is something to be done while sending the address to the contract i.e **JS->CONTRACT**. But, i am not able to figure this out. Help would be really appreciated

Comment: Verify that you do not have empty spaces or invalid characters in the address, also would be helpful to see the contract function.

Comment: Debug if both ```user``` and ```account``` variables are valid ethereum addresses.